# How do I change this string into a date format?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a string from a data export that reads "2019-04-04T16:11:50Z" how do I convert this to a date format in excel?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. You will get a more positive response if you show what you have tried so far and that you've made a reasonable effort to solve the problem yourself. Show formulas, screenshots if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Find one way below.

Have a great day

[image]

Comment: You may also consider `LEFT(A1,4)` to `MID(A1,1,4)` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,4)&"-"&MID(A1,6,2)&"-"&MID(A1,9,2)&" "&MID(A1,12,2)&":"&MID(A1,15,2)&":"&MID(A1,18,2)
```

[image]